# printing piles in NIM game with assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm writing a [NIM game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) in assembly 8086 (with arbitrary number of piles and sticks, limited to maximum 45), but I'm new to assembly language.
it's not complete yet, and for now I want to print the piles with some ASCII character.

So I have written a procedure for printing them.
Here is my code for that part:

```
cr equ 0dh
nl equ 0ah
shape db '| ', '$'
new db cr, nl, '$'
pile1 db 5 dup ?

print_pile  proc
pusha 
mov si, 0
mov cx, piles ;copy number of piles to cx
xor bl, bl

pile_loop:
lea dx, shape 
mov bl, pile1[si] ;I have prompted user to enter the number of 
                  ;sticks for each pile beforehand.

    print_loop:
    call print_msg ;a proc for printing strings
    dec bl
    cmp bl, 0
    jnz print_loop

lea dx, new ;print new line
call print_msg     
inc si    
dec cx
cmp cx, 0
jnz pile_loop

popa
ret
print_pile endp
```

when I run it, it first set up pile1 array with sticks in each pile. but I face two problems:

1- When it copies pile1[0] to bl (mov bl, pile1[si]) it starts with my last entry. I suppose it should start with first one?

2- First loop (si = 0, cx = piles) is completed correctly (although it's last entry) and correct number of sticks are printed. but in second loop (si = 1, cx = piles-1) it copies 0x7C (124 decimal) to bl and prints 124 sticks. it's always 0x7C.

I don't know if using array is the efficient way to store sticks. but I could think of a way to use stack to store them.
I suppose there's a problem with the array pile1[].

PS. my complete code (up to now) can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/QOA4OR).
    and sorry for my English.

PS. I don't know if it helps, but I'm using emu8086 emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 107 of your entire code you are always moving AL at the same address because you forgot to increment SI.

```
mov     pile1[si], al
inc     si  ; <-- Forgotten
inc     bx
```

*1- When it copies pile1[0] to bl (mov bl, pile1[si]) it starts with my last entry. I suppose it should start with first one?*

I don't get what you mean. `mov bl,pile1[si]` just fills in a counter to repeat displaying identical shapes. Where do you see that it starts with the last entry?

EDIT

At line 28 you defined *piles* as a word by `piles dw ?`.
At line 82 you only wrote the low byte of *piles* with `mov b. piles,al`.
The assembler might not have written ZEROES at *piles* since it is free to interpret the **?** used in the **dw**. Better code `piles dw 0`

Comment: thanks. problem solved.
about that question, suppose I want to have 3 piles and I enter the number of sticks for each respectively: first = 4, second = 5, and last = 7. it would copy last one (7) correctly to bl in first loop time. As you mentioned my code was always moving AL the same address causing two first entered number overwrite by third one. and it seemed to me that first index of array is (7).
and second index would be a junk number (0x7C).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an issue with your posted code. The linked code has (at least ;-) ) two errors

1) Line 29:

Change

```
pile1 db 5 dup ?
```

to

```
pile1 db 5 dup (?)
```

2) Line 108:

Insert

```
inc si
```

as mentioned by user3144770.

Comment: thank you too.
changing ? to (?) solved another problem.
could you explain what using _"?"_ (without parenthesis) would mean? cause assembler didn't return any error, but it would print some junks instead of _"|"_ that I defined.

Comment: @Pooya: The syntax is: `number DUP (values) `  and means: `number` bytes/words/else (`db`/`dw`/else) with `values`. The question mark means: anything (doesn't matter). Without parenthesis the expression is wrong, but `emu8086` reserves in this case only one byte. So the following `shape` will be overwritten with the second and third pile. Then `new` will be overwritten and so on.